# C# Clicking A website button with a Program button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button

I'm using C# to try to make a button click something on the website.

So i have my webbrowser on my program but now i want this button to auto click "enter"

But this does not have an ID
it has 2 button and the 2 buttons have an idea

Code from the website:

```
<fieldset id="add-remove-buttons">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="add to cart" class="button">
    <a class="button continue" href="/shop">keep shopping</a>
</fieldset>
```

code that I've tried

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("add-remove-buttons").SetAttribute("value", "add to cart");
}
```

The 2 buttons are under Id "Add-Remove-Buttons" but the one that i want to click is the value of "Add to cart" can someone please help me?

Comment: <fieldset id="add-remove-buttons"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="add to cart" class="button"><a class="button continue" href="/shop">keep shopping</a></fieldset>

Comment: Can you please post the code you have written so far? This will make it easier to help you out